# jCarousel memory problem (probably a leak)

Tags: memory, jcarousel

In my project I use jCarousel (http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) plugin to dynamically display images and list them.

I wonder is anybode expirienced memory problems with this plugin?

I'm trying the following scenario:

> 1. Configure jCarousel to dynamically load images
> 2. periodically reset jCarousel and load new images

As the result IE requires more and more memory that is not cleaned by GC.

In sIEve I can see that elements used by jCarousel  (eved removed) are still used by somebody, but unfortunately I can't see see who is referencing on the node. The node is not marked as leak.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parent container's style "overflow:hidden;", you will find out what's going on.

When "warp" is set to "circular", and autoscrolling proceed, jCarousel will copy **entire** nodes each time it scrolled, and never removed.

Sorry for that I'm searching for solution either. Wish you have solved the problem.